# React Extension Not working chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I've installer react extension on react but not able to use it as i'm facing an error

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/injectGlobalHook.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME